# Flutter still tries to build APK with uninstalled JDK

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have uninstalled my OpenJDK_17.0.6 and downgraded to OracleJDK_1.8.0_381
When I am running `flutter build apk -v` it is still trying to build it with the openJDK 17.
here is the log

> [   +8 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. [   +2 ms] * What
> went wrong: [        ] Could not determine java version from '17.0.6'.
> [        ] * Try: [        ] Run with --debug option to get more log
> output. [        ] * Exception is: [        ]
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version
> from '17.0.6'. [        ]     at
> org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:72) [        ]
> at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:82) [        ]
> at
> org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(Unsup
> portedJavaRuntimeException.java:42) [        ]    at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidatio
> nAction.java:32) [        ]   at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidatio
> nAction.java:24) [        ]   at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingActio
> n.java:33) [        ]     at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingActio
> n.java:22) [        ]     at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLine
> ActionFactory.java:246) [        ]    at
> org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLine
> ActionFactory.java:182) [        ]    at
> org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33) [        ]    at
> org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45) [
> ]     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) [        ]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source) [        ]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source) [        ]    at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [        ]
> at
> org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:6
> 0) [        ]     at
> org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
> [        ]    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
> [        ]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) [        ]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source) [        ]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source) [        ]    at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [        ]
> at
> org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
> [        ]    at
> org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129) [
> ]     at
> org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61) [
> ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org [  +34 ms] Running Gradle
> task 'assembleRelease'... (completed in 529ms) [   +5 ms] "flutter
> apk" took 20,334ms. [   +3 ms] Gradle task assembleRelease failed with
> exit code 1 [        ]
> #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
> #1      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp
> (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:456:9)
>
> #2      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildApk
> (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:208:5)
>
> #3      BuildApkCommand.runCommand
> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:116:5)
>
> #4      FlutterCommand.run.
> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1336:27)
>
> #5      AppContext.run.
> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
>
> #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.
> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:296:9)
>
> #8      AppContext.run.
> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:244:5)
>
> #10     run..
> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:91:9)
>
> #11     AppContext.run.
> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
>
> #12     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)

My java_home:

> **echo $JAVA_HOME** 
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-1.8.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Check `JAVA_HOME` env variable where it points to.

Comment: @Robert /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-1.8.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by upgrading the Gradle version in the gradle.properties file:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```

and gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```